# Disable downlaod link after 5 time clicks Wordpress | Javascripts | Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am creating a custom wordpress theme and what i want is that; there is a download  link, what i want is that users can download only 5 times when the user clicks that link only for 5 times, if the user tries to click the link  for the 6th time it automatically hides. I dont have any idea how to do this, also didn't find any relevant solution on google.

here below is my testing code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".gotocls").click(function(){
                alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
            });
        });
    }     
     </script>

    <a class="dkpdf-button gotocls" onclick="myFunction()" href="downlaod/image.com" target="_blank"><span class="dkpdf-button-icon"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></span> <?php echo $pdfbutton_text;?></a>
```

**i think this might be done with ajax, but i dont have much knowledge of ajax**

Comment: I think you didn't search right. Try again. Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need `onClick` in this code I add   `document.getElementsByClassName('gotocls')[0].style.display = 'none';` when i equals 5 .

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var i = 0
            $(".gotocls").click(function(){
                i++
                     if(i == 5)
                         document.getElementsByClassName('gotocls')[0].style.display = 'none';
                 alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!" + i);
            });
        });
 
     </script>

    <a class="dkpdf-button gotocls" id="myLink" href="downlaod/image.com"  target="_blank"><span class="dkpdf-button-icon"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></span> <?php echo $pdfbutton_text;?></a>
```

Comment: Yes, this code is working fine for me bruh,.....but if  the user refreshes the page it again re-lodes the 5 clicks, how do i permanently save the clicks so that if user again refreshes the page , he got the old remaining clicks.... for example:- i have 5 clicks, i used 2 clicks, after again login/logout i need to have remaining 3 clicks not all again 5 clicks.

Comment: You can get Ip address from site visitors. But I'm little busy for now. I can write Answer a few hours later.

Comment: yes , thankyou i am waiting for your answer.....at the mean time i try myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to hide the download link in the current session, then simple javascript should do your job.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var counter = 0;
  function myFunction() {
    if(counter === 5){
        document.getElementsByClassName('gotocls')[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
    counter = counter +1;
  }     
</script>
```

However when the user refreshes the site, then the download link will be visible again. If you want to store information permanently then you have to use a database.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code needed real quick with no tests but it should give you a starting point at least, in your PHP:

```
/**
 * Enqueue a JS file using WP proper action and functions
 * 'my-custom-script' can be any name of your fantasy, prepend it with your vendor name and you are good to go
 * 'url_to_js_file' MUST be a full URL to your .JS file containing the ajax you need
 */
function our_custom_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'my-custom-script', 'url_to_js_file.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-custom-script', 'myJsVarName', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), // Used to make ajax call in WP
    ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-script' );
}

// Load script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'our_custom_scripts' );


/**
 * What the ajax call will actually trigger thanks to WP AJAX handle
 */
function my_ajax_action() {
    /** @var wpdb $wpdb */
    global $wpdb;
    $clickedLink = $_POST["clicked_link"];
    $userId      = get_current_user_id();
    
    /*
     * Query for the pressed link, that's up to you on how to store data in the database, im going with an easy one
     * saving the full link (i would really NOT recommend this :D, its just to show)
     */
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}my_table_name WHERE link = %s";
    $res = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, array( $clickedLink ) ) );
    if ( $canClick = $res["num_pressed"] < 5 ) {
        $wpdb->update(
            $wpdb->prefix . "my_table_name",
            array(
                'num_pressed' => ( $res["num_pressed"] + 1 ),
                'string_col'  => 'val2', //example string col
                'int_col'     => 3, //example int col
            ),
            array( "user_id" => $userId ), // Where condition
            array( "%d", "%s", "%d" ), // updated values format. %s are for strings, %d for integers
            array( "%d" ) );// Where condition format
        wp_send_json_success();
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax_action', array( $this, 'my_ajax_action' ) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_action', array( $this, 'my_ajax_action' ) );
```

Then in your .js file add this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".gotocls").click(function (evt) {
                var $pressedLink = $(this);
                evt.preventDefault(); // Stop doing w/e the browser was trying to do
                $.ajax({
                    url:      myJsVarName.ajaxurl,
                    type:     'POST',
                    data:     {
                        action:       'my_ajax_action',
                        clicked_link: $pressedLink.attr("href")
                    },
                    timeout:  5000
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:  function (response) {
                        console.log('Your response content', response);
                        if (response.success) {
                            window.location.href = $pressedLink.attr("href"); // Proceed with click
                        }
                    },
                    error:    function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

This should cover the PHP and the JS side of your stuff. The rest is up to you, stackoverflow is not a coding factory, it's a community for advices :D